# SQL - Calculating cell-value based on other cell-values

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have run into a problem when working on some SQL coding.
I have a data table that looks somewhat like this:

```
ID  TimeID    IndicatorID      Score   
1     111         45             20
1     111         46             14
1     111         47             83
1     111         48             91
1     112         45             20
1     112         46             14
1     112         47             83
1     112         48             91
2     111         45             25
2     111         46             12
2     111         47             70
2     111         48             82
2     112         45             25
2     112         46             12
2     112         47             70
2     112         48             82
```

I want to add new rows containing values for indicator 240 and 241 where the score for indicator 240 is the score for indicator 45 / score for indicator 46  and similarly the score for indicator 241 is the score for indicator 47/ score for indicator 48. This has to be done for each TimeID for each ID.

The full table is huge as the number of IDs, TimeIDs for each ID, and IndicatorIDs for each TimeID is large.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your requirements are as stated, and all the `IndicatorID` values are hard-coded this can be done with some simply sub-queries and a straightforward INSERT statement:

```
insert into your_table
with yt as (
    select * from your_table where IndicatorID in (45,46,47,48)
    )
    , yt45 as (select * from yt where IndicatorID = 45 )
    , yt46 as (select * from yt where IndicatorID = 46 )
    , yt47 as (select * from yt where IndicatorID = 47 )
    , yt48 as (select * from yt where IndicatorID = 48 )
select yt45.id
      , yt45.timeID
      , 240 as IndicatorID
      , yt45.score/yt46.score as score
from yt45
     join yt46
     on yt45.id = yt46.id 
         and yt45.timeID = yt46.timeID 
union all
select yt47.id
       , yt47.timeID
       , 240 as IndicatorID
       , yt47.score/yt48.score as score
from yt47
     join yt48
     on yt47.id = yt48.id 
         and yt47.timeID = yt48.timeID 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved using [MODEL clause](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/10gr1-twp-bi-dw-sqlmodel-131067.pdf).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662589/3)

```
select id, timeid, indicatorid, score
from myt
model return updated rows
partition by (id, timeid)
dimension by (indicatorid)
measures(score)
rules(
  score[240] = score[45]/score[46],
  score[241] = score[47]/score[48]
  );
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662589/2/0)**:

```
| ID | TIMEID | INDICATORID |              SCORE |
|----|--------|-------------|--------------------|
|  2 |    111 |         241 | 0.8536585365853658 |
|  2 |    111 |         240 | 2.0833333333333335 |
|  1 |    112 |         241 | 0.9120879120879121 |
|  1 |    112 |         240 | 1.4285714285714286 |
|  2 |    112 |         241 | 0.8536585365853658 |
|  2 |    112 |         240 | 2.0833333333333335 |
|  1 |    111 |         241 | 0.9120879120879121 |
|  1 |    111 |         240 | 1.4285714285714286 |


insert into myt
select id, timeid, indicatorid, score
from myt
model return updated rows
partition by (id, timeid)
dimension by (indicatorid)
measures(score)
rules(
  score[240] = score[45]/score[46],
  score[241] = score[47]/score[48]
  );
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662589/3/1)**:

```
select id, timeid, indicatorid, score
from myt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/662589/3/2)**:

```
| ID | TIMEID | INDICATORID |              SCORE |
|----|--------|-------------|--------------------|
|  1 |    111 |          45 |                 20 |
|  1 |    111 |          46 |                 14 |
|  1 |    111 |          47 |                 83 |
|  1 |    111 |          48 |                 91 |
|  1 |    111 |         240 | 1.4285714285714286 |
|  1 |    111 |         241 | 0.9120879120879121 |
|  1 |    112 |          45 |                 20 |
|  1 |    112 |          46 |                 14 |
|  1 |    112 |          47 |                 83 |
|  1 |    112 |          48 |                 91 |
|  1 |    112 |         240 | 1.4285714285714286 |
|  1 |    112 |         241 | 0.9120879120879121 |
|  2 |    111 |          45 |                 25 |
|  2 |    111 |          46 |                 12 |
|  2 |    111 |          47 |                 70 |
|  2 |    111 |          48 |                 82 |
|  2 |    111 |         240 | 2.0833333333333335 |
|  2 |    111 |         241 | 0.8536585365853658 |
|  2 |    112 |          45 |                 25 |
|  2 |    112 |          46 |                 12 |
|  2 |    112 |          47 |                 70 |
|  2 |    112 |          48 |                 82 |
|  2 |    112 |         240 | 2.0833333333333335 |
|  2 |    112 |         241 | 0.8536585365853658 |
```

Comment: Nothing can be "easily solved" using the MODEL clause :)